# MS Access Text Field Special Characters

Tags: ms-access, special-characters

I have a search button that executes this `applyfilter` macro code:

`[ContractNumber] Like "*" & [Forms]![frmContractMatch&Revenue]![Text44] & "*"`

So it searches text box `text44` for the appropriate `ContractNumber`. The trouble I am having is that if a contract number is `ART#45` for example, it will not find it in the database because of the special character `#`.

How do I get around this? The problem is that the contracts could have different special characters or they may have none at all, so I can't tell it to specifically search for a particular symbol all the time.

Comment: I'm not entirely convinced that # is your issue in this case, try `[ContractNumber] Like "'*" & [Forms]![frmContractMatch&Revenue]![Text44] & "*'"` (Notice the single quotes to show it is a string).

Comment: In addition to `#`, what other special characters do you need to cope with?

Comment: I tried the single quotes, but to no avail. I'm not sure what other special characters I'll be dealing with, but it would be nice if the code could be built to handle multiple special characters. Right now it only works if I search for a ContractNumber that is all text or numbers ex: "LRV57" or if I search for only the text part ex: ART". The instant I put in a # sign it finds nothing.

Comment: When you say code, do you actually mean Access macro or actual VBA code?

Comment: oops, just the macro with the where condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access uses the # as a wildcard for a single number field. When you create a search field and include #, such as ART#, Access interprets this as "I'm searching for the string 'ART' followed by a single numeric character 0-9" It uses a '?','%', and '-' similarly. To get around this, you need to alter the input string and enclose the literal special character in square brackets. so instead of searching for:

```
'ART#'
```

You would search for:

```
'ART[#]'
```

how do you get around this?  depends on how you are entering the search criteria. This area is not really my strong suit, but depending on how the search is entered you could probably use a custom function to add the square brackets to your parameter before filtering the form. I personally would prevent the use of special characters in the order number thru code.

Comment: Okay thanks! we will eliminate the use of special characters as I think it will expedite the process.